# Corrected Odometry from GMapping / Karto?

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been building (2D) maps using GMapping, and visualizing the results in rviz. So far, so good. However, the tf frames that are available (/odom -> /base_link, most importantly) represent the original, dead-reckoning, uncorrected odometry.

So far as I can tell, GMapping and Karto don't publish an extra, "corrected odometry" frame that I could use to visualize the current best hypothesis about the robot's pose.

Have I missed something, or do I need to put in a feature request?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9107/corrected-odometry-from-gmapping-/-karto?/) by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4119 on 2011-02-17

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) explains the relationship between these transform frames in more detail.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Localization services like gmapping, karto, and amcl publish the transform from /map -> /odom.  This transform is the correction for the accumulated drift in the odometry as measured by the localization.  If the odometry was perfect this transform would always be zero.  So the "corrected odometry" is the net transform from /map to /odom to /base_link.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've found it useful to add an additional frame to the standard tree: `map->scanmatch_corrected_odom->odom`

You can write the necessary code for karto to publish this transform, but we've found the [Canonical Scan Matcher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher) to perform very quickly and accurately while publishing local scan-match results out-of-the-box

---

Originally posted by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) with karma: 481 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1